# cant keep the updated input value when swapping box

Tags: javascript, html

This is a code to create boxes that can be swapped one another

The input box keep on return default value when I swapped the boxes

I tried non-input(text based value and it returns just fine.

need the input box to be updated as usual (like the bottom one but input)

**edit:**

you are right @tacoshy should have use class instead, im sorry i will update the step to produce the bug:

1. open the colapsible tab.
2. edit one of the input inside
3. unfocus the input ( it supposed to update its value when unfocus)
4. try to swap the boxes.( the input text will go back to the default
   value where the text beside are fine)

codepen :    `https://codepen.io/slipless/pen/KKBVemr`

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test">B</div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="te"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  <div class="item8">
    <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  </div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
  <div draggable="true" class="box"><input type="text" id="inputField" onkeyup="handleKeyUp()" value="test"></div>
</div>
```

**edit2 :**
it worked now but my code are acting strange after i did edit on Onblur()

```
  var element = event.target;
  var element2 = event.target.parentNode;
  var input = element;
  input.defaultValue = element.value; // fix
  element2.innerHTML = "";// element2.innerHTML = ""+input.value;
  element.value = element2.innerHTML;
  element2.appendChild(input);
```

the string inside the input are null after unfocus and it worked normal after I do swap the boxes

It worked normally after i open this comment but i want this to be input only

```
// element2.innerHTML = ""+input.value;
```

**edit3 :**
after some edit it works for now thx for help!

```
  var element = event.target;
  var element2 = event.target.parentNode;
  var input = element;
  input.defaultValue = element.value; // fix
  element2.innerHTML = "";// element2.innerHTML = ""+input.value;
  element2.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: As side-note: an id has to be unique. It can not be re-used multiple times

Comment: you are right @tacoshy should have use class instead, im sorry i will update the step to produce the bug:
1. open the colapsible tab.
2. edit one of the input inside
3. unfocus the input ( it supposed to update its value when unfocus)
4. try to swap the boxes.( the input text will go back to the default value where the text beside are fine).

Comment: @mplungjan I use innerHTML on its parent not the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not obvious, but this fixed it

```
var element = event.target;
var element2 = event.target.parentNode;
var input = element;
input.defaultValue = input.value; // fix
element2.innerHTML = input.value; 
element.value = element2.innerHTML;
element2.innerHTML = input.value;
```

Comment: it was fixed as text, I want it to stay as input instead